# Error: The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled in php

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, codeigniter

I am using `php 7.2.10`, `mongodb 3.6.3` and `ubuntu-16.0.4`.

I have checked `mongodb.so` file is also there into the folder.

I have also enabled `extension=mongodb` in `php.ini` but still getting this:

```
Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongo'
```

How can I tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake here `extension=mongodb.so` not `extension=mongodb`. In microsoft Window use `extension=mongodb.dll`. This is the link for correct install http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php in ubuntu not ubantu